# Python Grequests + multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, grequests

I'm trying to make async http calls using grequests from within a Pool from the multiprocessing library. I'm encountering a problem that suggests Grequests and multiprocessing are possibly incompatible with each other; specifically, calling `monkey.patch_all()` messes with Pool creation.

Initially, without calling `monkey.patch_all()` in my code:

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
```

I get these two errors:

```
NotImplementedError: gevent is only usable from a single thread
```

and

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: None: Max retries exceeded with url: SOME_URL (Caused by redirect)
```

Calling `monkey.patch_all()` fixes the above errors, but causes my code to hang at:

```
p = Pool(THREAD_POOL_SIZE)
```

Not calling `monkey.patch_all()` leads to my Pool created successfully. Calling `monkey.patch_all(thread=False, socket=False)` leads to my Pool created successfully, too, but doesn't solve the initial two errors.

Comment: Gevent, multiprocessing don't play nice with each other.

Comment: two years old, but for those who come after, try: http://www.gevent.org/gevent.pool.html